# Binding Command in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I made UWP app with MVVM pattern(i think so :) )
My app have data template for listbox. 
ListBox in View.xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMySongs" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySongs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lbSongsTemplate}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox/>
```

DateTemplate resource:

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="lbSongsTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Artist}" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" - " Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Grid.Column="2"/>
            //Here i bind command, but it's not binding cos ItemsSource have no command. ViewModel have this command.
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DownloadCommand}" Content="{Binding Path=Query}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
```

Need to set DataContext for this button. 
My command in ViewModel. Example:

```
class ViewModel
{
    ...
    public RelayCommand DownloadCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> MySongs { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My problem: DataTemplate have ItemsSource = ViewModel.MySongs. But "DownloadCommand" is in ViewModel.
What i type in DataTemplate for my button set binding to DownloadCommand?

Comment: Select the Button -> Tap `F4` on your keyboard you will see properties -> search for Command -> Click Little Grey button after the text box, select Create Binding -> from the binding window select your `DownloadCommand` - > Voila

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DownloadCommand, ElementName=lbMySongs}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Content="{Binding Path=Query}"/>
```

And change

```
public RelayCommand DownloadCommand { get; set; }
```

to

```
public RelayCommand<SomeClass> DownloadCommand { get; set; }
...
DownloadCommand = new RelayCommand<SomeClass>(DownloadExecute);
...
private voir DownloadExecute(SomeClass item)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `RelativeSource` binding to say you want to bind to `ListBox.DataContext.DownloadCommand`

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DownloadCommand, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" 
        Content="{Binding Path=Query}"/>
```

Its often common practice like this to also bind the `CommandParameter` to the item to know what item the command was executed on :

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DownloadCommand, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding }"
        Content="{Binding Path=Query}" />
```

You could also use an `ElementName` binding, but then you have to give your `ListBox` a Name to specify in your DataTemplate, and I don't personally like to hardcode `ElementName` in my DataTemplates. Makes it annoying to find and fix if you change something's name, or want to use the DataTemplate in another ListBox.

Comment: This doesn't work in UWP as FindAncestor is not supported for RelativeSource bindings

Comment: @ndonohoe Ahhhh I forgot about that with UWP. A quick google search of "UWP FindAncestor" leads to [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32865846/302677) which contains a suggestion to use a DependencyProperty to provide this kind of behavior. I would personally try to setup something custom like this to replace the FindAncestor functionality than using ElementName, although if that failed using `ElementName` would always work. :)