# How to set a Binding from ItemTemplate to the hosting Container in an ItemsControl? (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, uwp

Given an arbitrary `ItemsControl`, like a `ListView`,  I want to set a Binding from inside the `ItemsTemplate` to the hosting Container. How can I do that easily? For example, in WPF we can do it using this inside the `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <SomeControl Property="{Binding Path=TargetProperty, RelativeSouce={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyContainer}}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In this example (for WPF) the **Binding** will be set between `Property` in `SomeControl` and `TargetProperty` of the `ListViewItem` (implicit, because it will be generated dynamically by the `ListView` to host the each of its items).

How can we do achieve the same in UWP?

I want something that is MVVM-friendly. Maybe with attached properties or an Interaction Behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861612/how-to-do-relativesource-mode-find-ancestor-or-equivalent-in-uwp

Comment: @WPFUser Sorry, but I don't see how that could be applied to my needs.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the ListViewItem is created implicitly, and not easy to get at. If you have any ideas on that score I'd be interested.

Comment: I wonder if we could create a derived ListView class in which you can include the ListViewItem in the DataTemplate, so it won't generate a new container, but use THAT explicit ListViewItem. The a Binding with ElementName could be used. Am I too imaginative?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think that might be troublesome. If you add a `ListViewItem` to the `DataTemplate`, you end up with a `ListViewItem` (yours) wrapped in a `ListViewItemPresenter` wrapped in yet another `ListViewItem`...

Comment: Couldn't that be handled inside the derived ListView so we can avoid duplicating containers?

Comment: Possibly. If you try to go that route I'd be interested in the results. (Which might end up as another answer to this question.)

Comment: Are you attempting to bind within the DataTemplate to something that is outside? Trying to understand if the question is around binding to main model properties from within ItemTemplate.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example, in a ListView, to bind a property of from inside the template to the containing ListiewItem. Sorry, the title is wrong 

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have just edited the original post to clarify it a bit. I want to bind a control inside the ItemTemplate to the container that is generated automatically to host the items. I would like something that is reusable and MVVM-friendly.

Comment: Please clarify the reasoning behind this requirement(e.g. the exact property you would like to bind). If it's not possible in UWP it usually is bad practice.

Comment: All use cases I could think of would be handled by adding an `ItemContainerStyle` in addition to the `ItemTemplate`, so it would really help if you explain an example use case where you feel that you need the requested functionality.

Comment: To all: I have a ItemsControl-derived class that generates a special kind of Container, called DesignerItem. This container has a property "IsEditing" which is a state controlled by itself. When the IsEditing property is true, I want to show make a Toolbar visible. This toolbar is INSIDE the ItemTemplate. So I have to bind the Visibility property of the Toobar to the IsEditing property of the DesignerItem (the Container).

Comment: So in short, either your viewmodel knows about `IsEditing` or you don't have a `DataTemplate` at all, because (as the name implies) a DataTemplate is meant as a way to display a certain set of data and not as a way to interact with its parent containers.

Comment: @grek40 My ViewModel doesn't have to know about the changes in the IsEditing property, but the items inside the template should. The items inside DataTemplate should act upon changes in this property. The problem comes from the fact that the IsEditing is exclusive responsibility of the Container.

Comment: @grek40 So, in short, when the Container decides it's time in editing mode (IsEditing=true), the toolbar inside the ItemTemplate should handle the change. Otherwise I would have to pass the responsibility of handing the user interaction to the ViewModel, that in my case, isn't aware and shouldn't be aware of the state of the container.

Comment: @grek40 It's entirely a concert of the views. In my scenario, when the user double taps a container, it enters in "EditMode". In such state, the toolbar (defined inside the ItemTemplate) should be shown. But since the IsEditing property is defined into the container, I need a way to link those properties (Visibility and IsEditing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this answer is based on WPF, there might be some changes necessary for UWP.

There are basically two cases to consider:

1. You have a data driven aspect that needs to be bound to the item container
2. You have a view-only property

Lets assume a customized listview for both cases:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new DesignerItem();
    }
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is DesignerItem;
    }
}
public class DesignerItem : ListViewItem
{
    public bool IsEditing
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEditingProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditing", typeof(bool), typeof(DesignerItem));
}
```

In case 1, you can use the `ItemContainerStyle` to link your viewmodel property with a binding and then bind the same property inside the datatemplate

```
class MyData
{
    public bool IsEditing { get; set; } // also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged here!
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:MyListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}">
    <local:MyListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DesignerItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="{Binding IsEditing,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </local:MyListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Red" Margin="5" Padding="5">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEditing}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:MyListView>
```

In case 2, it appears that you don't really have a data driven property and consequently, the effects of your property should be reflected within the control (`ControlTemplate`).

In the following example a toolbar is made visible based on the `IsEditing` property. A togglebutton can be used to control the property, the `ItemTemplate` is used as an inner element next to the toolbar and button, it knows nothing of the `IsEditing` state:

```
<local:MyListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}">
    <local:MyListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DesignerItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="{Binding IsEditing,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DesignerItem}">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding IsEditing,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Edit"/>
                            <!--Toolbar is something control related, rather than data related-->
                            <ToolBar x:Name="MyToolBar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Button Content="Tool"/>
                            </ToolBar>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MyToolBar" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </local:MyListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Red" Margin="5" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:MyListView>
```

For a better control template, you may chose to use Blend and create the control template starting at the full `ListViewItem` template and just editing your changes into it.

If your DesignerItem generally has a specific enhanced appearance, consider designing it in the `Themes/Generic.xaml` with the appropriate default style.

---

As commented, you could provide a separate data template for the editing mode. To do this, add a property to `MyListView` and to `DesignerItem` and use `MyListView.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(...)` to transfer the template.

In order to apply the template without the need for `Setter.Value` bindings, you can use value coercion on `DesignerItem.ContentTemplate` based on `IsEditing`.

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new DesignerItem();
    }
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is DesignerItem;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        var elem = element as DesignerItem;
        elem.ContentEditTemplate = ItemEditTemplate;
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemEditTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemEditTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemEditTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemEditTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemEditTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MyListView));
}

public class DesignerItem : ListViewItem
{
    static DesignerItem()
    {
        ContentTemplateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DesignerItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceContentTemplate)));
    }
    private static object CoerceContentTemplate(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var self = d as DesignerItem;
        if (self != null && self.IsEditing)
        {
            return self.ContentEditTemplate;
        }
        return baseValue;
    }

    private static void OnIsEditingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(ContentTemplateProperty);
    }

    public bool IsEditing
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEditingProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditing", typeof(bool), typeof(DesignerItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsEditingChanged)));

    public DataTemplate ContentEditTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ContentEditTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentEditTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ContentEditTemplate.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentEditTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ContentEditTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DesignerItem));
}
```

Note, for an easier example I will activate the "edit" mode by `ListViewItem.IsSelected` with some trigger:

```
<local:MyListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}">
    <local:MyListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DesignerItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:MyListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Red" Margin="5" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
    <local:MyListView.ItemEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Green" Margin="5" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyListView.ItemEditTemplate>
</local:MyListView>
```

Intended behavior: the selected item becomes edit-enabled, getting the `local:MyListView.ItemEditTemplate` (green) instead of the default template (red)

Comment: Ofcourse, with a custom itemscontrol and itemcontainer, there is also the possibility to just have more templates in the itemscontrol like an additional `local:MyListView.ItemEditTemplate` and make the `ItemContainer` swap between templates for editing.

Comment: I'm interested in what you say. How would I swap between the regular and editing templates? I think you cannot just change the ItemTemplate (hotswapping). Do you?

Comment: By the way, I think you cannot put a Binding as a Value in a Setter in UWP :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573929/uwp-binding-in-style-setter-not-working

Comment: @SuperJMN I'm not sure, but it's just talking about styles, so with some huge amount of luck, the `ControlTemplate.Triggers-Setter.Value` binding will still work :)

Comment: @SuperJMN haha :) see my edit for a different way to handle the active content template (I reworked the part below the horizontal line in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

When the selection changes, search the visual tree for the radio button with the `DataContext` corresponding to selected/deselected items. Once it's found, you can check/uncheck at your leisure.

I have a toy model object looking like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My `Page` is named `self` and contains this collection property:

```
public Data[] Data { get; set; } =
    {
        new Data { Name = "One" },
        new Data { Name = "Two" },
        new Data { Name = "Three" },
    };
```

The list view, binding to the above collection:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=self}"
    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `SelectionChanged` event handler:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lv = sender as ListView;

    var removed = FindRadioButtonWithDataContext(lv, e.RemovedItems.FirstOrDefault());
    if (removed != null)
    {
        removed.IsChecked = false;
    }

    var added = FindRadioButtonWithDataContext(lv, e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault());
    if (added != null)
    {
        added.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Finding the radio button with a `DataContext` matching our `Data` instance:

```
public static RadioButton FindRadioButtonWithDataContext(
    DependencyObject parent,
    object data)
{
    if (parent != null)
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            ListViewItem lv = child as ListViewItem;
            if (lv != null)
            {
                RadioButton rb = FindVisualChild<RadioButton>(child);
                if (rb?.DataContext == data)
                {
                    return rb;
                }
            }

            RadioButton childOfChild = FindRadioButtonWithDataContext(child, data);
            if (childOfChild != null)
            {
                return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And finally, a helper method to find a child of a specific type:

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(
    DependencyObject parent)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent != null)
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            T candidate = child as T;
            if (candidate != null)
            {
                return candidate;
            }

            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
            {
                return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

The result:

[image]

This will break if a given model instance shows up more than once in the list.

Comment: That is a nice way to achieve the same result, but it has some drawbacks: it's not reusable, adds a lot of boilerplate, and it looks like a hack. Why did they have to remove the best features of WPF?

Comment: Heh. My own favorite missing piece from WPF is custom markup extensions. I'm sure it's possible to package my solution in a more palatable and reusable way, though; I just went the quickest way from A to B.

Comment: My last helper method, for example, is a utility I use quite often.

Comment: Cool! I have just asked about creating custom MarkupExtensions in UWP (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245320/custom-markupextension-in-uwp). INCREDIBLE Bummer.

Comment: I just amended the code to get rid of the model class dependency. A slight improvement towards reusability.

Comment: Sorry, but after a year of the OP, I have decided to remove the accepted answer check because this kind of solution is far from being MVVM friendly and is valid only for this scenario (selection of items). If I want to bind to an arbitrary property of the container, you're in trouble again.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you might want to have an `IsSelected` property in your view model item class, you may create a derived ListView that establishes a Binding of its ListViewItems to the view model property:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public string ItemIsSelectedPropertyName { get; set; } = "IsSelected";

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(element,
            ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty,
            new Binding
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(ItemIsSelectedPropertyName),
                Source = item,
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            });
    }
}
```

You might now simply bind the RadioButton's `IsChecked` property in the ListView's ItemTemplate to the same view model property:

```
<local:MyListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Content}"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:MyListView>
```

In the above example the data item class also has `Content` property. Obviously, the `IsSelected` property of the data item class must fire a PropertyChanged event.