# How to Bind ItemsSource of ComboBox in ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

### Situation

I have to change the content of the `Flyout` Item in GridView. So I am creating `ControlTemplate` in `Page.Resources` and setting it in `ContentControl` which is inside `Flyout`.

### Problem

I have a `ComboBox` in `ControlTemplate`. Now I want to set the `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox` to `List<string>` (`_easingType`) which is declared in `MainPage`

### Question

How to Bind/Set `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox` in `ControlTemplate`?

### Code

I have removed the unnecessary parts of the code

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BlurEditFlyout">
        ....
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Bind it to the _esaingType}" />
        ....
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BlurEditFlyout">
</Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind _items}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MethodData">
            <StackPanel>
                ....
                <Button Visibility="{x:Bind EditButtonVisibility}">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout>
                            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                                </Style>
                            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <ContentControl Template="{x:Bind FlyoutTemplate}"/>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit"/>
                </Button>
                ....
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    ObservableCollection<MethodData> _items = new ObservableCollection<MethodData>();
    List<string> _easingType = new List<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(EasingType)).ToArray());
    Dictionary<MethodName, ControlTemplate> _buttonFlyoutDictionary = new Dictionary<MethodName, ControlTemplate>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        LoadFlyoutResources();

        _items.Add(GetMethodData(MethodName.Blur));
    }

    private void LoadFlyoutResources()
    {
        _buttonFlyoutDictionary.Add(MethodName.Blur, (ControlTemplate)Resources["BlurEditFlyout"]);
        .....
    }

    private MethodData GetMethodData(MethodName methodName)
    {
        _buttonFlyoutDictionary.TryGetValue(methodName, out ControlTemplate flyoutTemplate);
        return new MethodData(methodName, flyoutTemplate);
    }
}

public class MethodData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ControlTemplate FlyoutTemplate { get; set; }
    public Visibility EditButtonVisibility { get; set; }

    public MethodData(MethodName name, ControlTemplate flyoutTemplate)
    {
        Name = name.ToString();
        FlyoutTemplate = flyoutTemplate;
        EditButtonVisibility = (name == MethodName.Then) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
}

public enum MethodName
{
    Blur,
    ....
}
```

### Full Code

[AnimationSetSamplePage.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xnefuqqurbq0jkj/AnimationSetSamplePage.zip)

Comment: Why are those fields declared outside of the MainPage class?

Comment: While you indicated that `unnecessary parts of the code` were removed, you still need to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Sorry it is a mistake while pasting the code. I have already provided a minimalistic example. `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Bind it to the _esaingType}" />` this line explains everything.

Comment: @Nkosi Here is my full code. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xnefuqqurbq0jkj/AnimationSetSamplePage.zip

Comment: @Nkosi Any update?

Comment: This looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861612/how-to-do-relativesource-mode-find-ancestor-or-equivalent-in-uwp#32865846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DataContext in the Flyout control is actually each item in "_items".  You'll want to create a DataContext proxy to get to your Page's DataContext.  You can follow either of these two links to create the proxy.

https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls

http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

The gist of it is you'll want to create a proxy that you can reference as a static resource.  Following the first link, you'll do something like this:

```
public class DataContextProxy : FrameworkElement
{
    public DataContextProxy()
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataContextProxy_Loaded);
    }

    void DataContextProxy_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BindingPropertyName))
        {
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(BindingPropertyName);
        }
        binding.Source = this.DataContext;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode;
        this.SetBinding(DataContextProxy.DataSourceProperty, binding);             
    }

    public Object DataSource
    {
        get { return (Object)GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof(Object), typeof(DataContextProxy), null);


    public string BindingPropertyName { get; set; }

    public BindingMode BindingMode { get; set; }

}
```

You should use `public` access modifier for `_easingType`

```
public List<string> _easingType = new List<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(EasingType)).ToArray());
```

In MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>        
    <local:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BlurEditFlyout">
        ....
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=DataSource._easingType}" />
        ....
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BlurEditFlyout">
</Page.Resources>
...
```

Comment: I have added more code to make this solution complete. Feel free to revert back the change.

Comment: Nope, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Bind/Set `ItemsSource` of ComboBox in ControlTemplate?

I'm not sure if you have deep reasons for asking this question, but directly to reply this question, we could just set the string list `_esaingType` as the value of `DataContext` property and binding it. For example:

XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter"  x:Key="BlurEditFlyout" >
      ...                   
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
      ...
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">  
    <Button>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BlurEditFlyout}">                                
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <!--<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource BlurEditFlyout}"/>-->
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit"/>
    </Button> 
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
List<string> _easingType = new List<string>();  
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   _easingType.Add("test2");
   _easingType.Add("test1");
   this.DataContext = _easingType;
}
```

Any concerns on this way or any issues when using this on your side please kindly tell me I will follow up in time. More details please reference [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

Comment: It's not working. I think it is because of my `Flyout` is inside `ItemTemplate` of `GridView`